# How can I install Ubuntu 19.04 desktop on Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v

I have hyper-v running on Windows Server 2019.  I can install Ubuntu 19.04 desktop but it fails during startup on "Started Gnome".

Is this way of running Ubuntu even possible?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-windows-ubuntu-hyperv-containers#0

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian on Hyper-V a lot and never had this issue, although I haven't tried with Buster yet.

Can you try one of the Ubuntu spins such as XUbuntu to see if it's GUI specific?

If you click on the VM that's trying to boot and press ctrl+alt+F1 can you switch to a terminal window? I just want to know if it's not booting to a GUI or if it's outright hanging.

Comment: I repeated the installation, and this time it went past "Starting GNOME Display Manager ..." but still froze at "Started tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures."

Comment: There was no response to Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed AGAIN, this time electing to use LVM.

This meant that the grub menu came up on boot, allowing me into recovery mode.

I disabled wayland, rebooted, and I can now get it to start and log in.

Looks like wayland and Hyper-V is an issue?